# Building a composite control with nested items

Tags: .net, asp.net, custom-server-controls, composite-controls

My goal is to create a composite control that looks like, acts like and behaves like a RadioButtonList.  There is some extra things done behind the scenes which are working no problem.  What I am unable to accomplish is the desired markup to use the control.  My ideal markup looks like this:

```
<cc1:RadioButtonField ID="rfCardType" runat="server" Title="Card Type:">
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="MasterCard" />
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Visa" />
    <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Text="Amex" />
</cc1:RadioButtonField>
```

What I would like to do is pass the `<asp:ListItems`> to the RadioButtonList in the composite control and have that handle everything required to produce/run the control.

**Control Markup** for RadioButtonField:

```
<div class="Title"> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="rblField" />
</div>
<div class="Text">
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblField" runat="server" Visible="true">
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
</div>
```

**Code Behind** for RadioButtonField:

```
???
```

What does the RadioButtonField code behind need to do in order to collect the `<asp:ListItems`> and pass them to the RadioButtonList?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the `<ListItem>` style markup, here's what you'll have to do:

1. Add an `items` private field of type `ListItemCollection` to your composite control
2. Add an `Items` public property of type `ListItemCollection` to your composite control.  The getter should refer to the `items` private field.
3. Add the [`ParseChildren`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.parsechildrenattribute.aspx) class attribute to your composite control so it will read the list.

Your composite control now has the ability to read `ListItem` nodes from its markup.  When the control renders, all `<ListItem>` nodes will be added to the private `items` collection.

It would be wonderful if you could now just set the `Items` member of the RadioButtonList, but unfortunately it is private.  You will have to `foreach` through the `items` field and call the `Add()` method on your child RadioButtonList.

Comment: That does the trick.  Now how would I achieve intellisense displaying the asp:ListItem as the available option?

Comment: Once the attribute is added and wired to the Items public property it should happen automatically.

Comment: It isn't happening automatically... hmmm

Comment: Have you looked up the usage of the ParseChildren attribute?  I think it should be "ParseChildren(true, "Items")" where "Items" is the public ListCollection property...

Comment: Yes that's what I have, but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Found it- you also need the PersistChildren attribute set to false.  http://www.west-wind.com/WebLog/posts/200.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
[PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.innerProperty)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerilizationVisibility.Content)]
ListCollection Items
{
}
```

Maybe try this two attributes.
The `PersistChildrenAttribute` only provides designer support for your control with Visual Studio. `DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content` serializes the contents of the collection data type